# Google charts geochart - text values in colorAxis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to render Google Geochart chart on my page and it renders okay. The only problem with the chart is the scale (colorAxis). As far as I know, from the developers guide, user can put values and colors that should be available on the scale.

The problem is, that I can put there only number values and I would like to change the scale, so it contains four text values - "low, medium, hard, extreme".

[image]

Is there any way to change the 1-4 scale to text scale, so min and max values on the scale would be strings, not integers.

I've already tried to put strings in `colorAxis.minValue` and `colorAxis.maxValue` but then, chart just ignores that.

Answer (score 0):

`colorAxis.minValue` and `colorAxis.maxValue` according to `Google Charts` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) are used for:

> If present, specifies a minimum value for chart color data. Color data
>   values of this value and lower will be rendered as the first color in
>   the colorAxis.colors range.

What you want to change is the *legend* of the chart. I tried some options, but the best thing i could manage is simply add a string before min and max values with the following option.

```
var options = {
    legend: {
        numberFormat: "test"
    }
};
```

Jsfiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qwrtsyft/).